# Laravel DB::select returns General error: 2031

Tags: laravel

Laravel `DB::select` returns

> General error: 2031

It looks like quotes are not added to the statement and it tries to execute the statement like this:

```
$sql = 'SELECT id FROM users where email=email@email.com';
```

The code looks like this:

```
$sql = 'SELECT id FROM users where email=?';
$results = DB::select($sql, ['email' => $email]);
```

I thought this is handled automatically by PDO but do I need to add anything to the code above so the statement looks like?

```
$sql = 'SELECT id FROM users where email="email@email.com"';
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend you to read the [select docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries#selects) from Laravel Query Builder.

The Query Builder provides a complete API to make it easier and safer. Your query would look like:

```php
$results = DB::table("users")->select("id")->where("email",$email);
```

**EDIT**

The problem is that you're trying to pass a named parameter, but inside the string you didn't named it.

As the doc example shows:

```php
$results = DB::select('select * from users where id = :id', ['id' => 1]);
```

Your query should look like:

```php
$sql = 'SELECT id FROM users where email=:email';
$results = DB::select($sql, ['email' => $email]);
```

Comment: Even simpler, this can be trimmed down to `where("email" ,$email)`. The operator's only necessary if you're not using `=`.

Comment: I think that clarifies the issues. Based also on some other advice I'm trying to use Eloquent whenever possible. But DB selects might be also sometimes very useful. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

@mthrsj has correctly identified a better solution in your *particular* query.

Your underlying issue with the `DB::select` call is you're using non-named placeholders `?` while passing it named data.

This should work:

```
$sql = 'SELECT id FROM users where email=?';
$results = DB::select($sql, [$email]);
```

as should this:

```
$sql = 'SELECT id FROM users where email=:email';
$results = DB::select($sql, ['email' => $email]);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have models setup, you can also call the DB using your User model:

```
$user = User::select('id')->where('email', $email)->get();
```

This uses Eloquent, which uses PDO.

Comment: Both Eloquent and the `DB` facade use PDO, but this is otherwise a good point - in general, use Eloquent where possible.

Comment: This is useful. Thanks.